# "Я не знаю что больнее" запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

"Я не знаю что больнее", нужна ли здесь запятая? Я так понимаю, что "что" в данном предложении — местоимение. Если запятая нужна, то почему?

Answer (score 1):

***Я не знаю, что больнее.***

Это сложноподчиненное предложение(СПП) с придаточным изъяснительным. Запятая ставится между главным и придаточным предложением.

***ЧТО*** — местоимение в роли союзного слова, в придаточном предложении оно является подлежащим, *больнее* — сказуемое.

Сравнить: ***Я знаю, что это больнее.***

Здесь ***ЧТО*** является союзом, а ***ЭТО*** — подлежащим.

Comment: Но тут нет "это"...

Comment: Я дала Вам вариант с "это" для сравнения, чтобы была понятна разница между союзом ЧТО (служебным словом) и союзным словом ЧТО (членом предложения). Ответ простой: запятая ставится в сложном предложении, но для этого надо увидеть, что предложение сложное. В нем две предикативные основы: "я не знаю" и "что больнее". Союзное слово ЧТО (местоимение) является подлежащим в придаточном предложении и одновременно служит  средством связи в сложноподчиненном  предложении (у него двойная роль).